# Adding a key to a dictionary based on a condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

As we can see in the below code, `rname` is added as a key if it exists else we are creating a structure without `rname`.

Is there any way we can handle this in a more elegant way, because this condition has to be checked in quite a lot of places in the code before creating objects. Can `rname` be added dynamically to the dictionary.

```
class AutoViviDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):

        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value


def some_function(rname, adapt, sw, class):

        d = AutoViviDict()

        if rname:
            d[rname][adapt][sw][class]= somevalue
        else:
            d[adapt][sw][class] = somevalue
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Atleast it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Not that your current code is too bad, but you could also do:

```
class AutoViviDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

def some_function(rname, adapt, sw, cls):
        d = AutoViviDict()
        d[adapt][sw][cls] = 1
        if rname:
            d = AutoViviDict({rname: d})
        return d
        # Or even just
        # return AutoViviDict({rname: d}) if rname else d

print(some_function('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}
print(some_function(None, 'b', 'c', 'd'))
# {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}
```

Comment: Thank you! this would definitely do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the duplicate code:

```
def some_function(rname, adapt, sw, cls, somevalue):
    d = AutoViviDict()
    if rname:
        d = d[rname]
    d[adapt][sw][cls] = somevalue
    return d
```

Comment: This wouldn't work it seems, if we consider @jdehesa's  example

`>>> print(some_function('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','somevalue'))
{'b': {'c': {'d': 'somevalue'}}}

>>> print(some_function(None, 'b', 'c', 'd','somevalue'))
{'b': {'c': {'d': 'somevalue'}}}`